# How I can make a table with if statements in python using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need help in my code.
My idea is take one value in the input (example: 1 ) and my code should return the tables that are respectively about my choice in the input, for later use this values for a create a super table ( with pd.merge() ) with all my values according to th evalue in the input.

This is a one example of my real code:

```
c = int(input('num'))

if c == 1:
    aa = [1,2]
    aaa = pd.DataFrame(aa,columns=['A'])
    
else:
    aaa = False
if c == 2:
    bb = [3,4]
    bbb = pd.DataFrame(bb,columns=['B'])
    
else:
    bbb = False
if c == 1:
    dd = [5,6]
    ddd = pd.DataFrame(dd,columns=['D'])
    
else:
    ddd =False
p = [aaa,bbb,ddd]
for k in p:
    if k != False:
         print(k)
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting your final result to be? A single data frame that tabulates what the user inputs?

Comment: In general I will expecting a table with the same rows but with all columns that with the input they was maked. example if in my code I have 3 conditions with 'if' ( in this case are tables) and if with the input at put 1  is generated only 2 conditions, I need that those conditions are put in only one table with the same rows but whit the columns respectively of each condition.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options. If the individual dataframes are small, you can place them in a dictionary and then retrieve the relevant one.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {
    k: pd.DataFrame(range(k, k+1), columns=list("abcde")[k:k+1])
    for k in range(4)
}

c = int(input('num'))

print(d.get(c))
```